# Modify dll function call in compiled exe

Tags: c++, executable, compiled

I have an exe file that I had written a while back and cannot find the source code for it (it was written in C++).

It calls the `MessageBoxA` function in `user32.dll` and passes necessary parameters to it. I want to modify the flags parameter to include the `MB_ICONERROR` (0x10) flag.

How do I go about finding which bytes in the exe file need to be modified to accomplish this?

Comment: Start with a short-prayer that your DLL *isn't* Authenticode-signed.

Comment: Step 1: Attach a debugger. Set a break point in MessageBoxA in user32. Trigger the dialog. Look at the call stack and track back up it to the call which specifies the flag you want to change. Modify the executable and recalculate the PE checksum. Step 2: Learn to use revision control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a disassembler like ICE or IDA. https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download.shtml. 
Load the executable. Find the Win32 API call on Names Window, to find it, just type the function name. Then double click CODE XREF to go to referenced caller.

[image]

Then you get what you want:
[image]

Just select the line and click on Hex-View to get the address.

[image]